# Spring Mockito: Null return on method call with specific arguments for repository mock

Tags: java, spring, mockito, repository, mockmvc

I try to mock the following repository and return a page of ToDo entries based on the name of the owner. I'm using 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'.

```
@Repository
public interface NotioRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDo, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<ToDo, Long> {
    Page<ToDo> findByOwner(String owner, Pageable pageable);
    ...
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/todos")
public class NotioController {

    private final NotioRepository notioRepository;

    public NotioController(NotioRepository notioRepository) {
        this.notioRepository = notioRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ToDo>> getToDos(Pageable pageable, Principal principal) {
        Page<ToDo> page = notioRepository.findByOwner(
                principal.getName(),
                PageRequest.of(
                        pageable.getPageNumber(),
                        pageable.getPageSize(),
                        pageable.getSortOr(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "done"))
                )
        );

        return ResponseEntity.ok(page.getContent());
    }

    ...
}
```

To reduce the time during tests I wanted to add some unit tests and only test the controller using the following test class:

```
@WebMvcTest(NotioController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.controller"})
public class NotioControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private NotioRepository notioRepository;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles="USER", username="tom")
    public void shouldReturnAPageWithUserSpecificToDos() throws Exception {
        ToDo[] toDos = {
                new ToDo(0L, "Get milk.", false, "tom"),
                new ToDo(1L, "Get bread.", true, "tom")
        };
        Page<ToDo> responsePage = new PageImpl<>(List.of(toDos));

        when(notioRepository.findByOwner("tom", PageRequest.of(0,2)))
                .thenReturn(responsePage);

        mvc.perform(
                get("/api/todos")
                        .param("page", "0")
                        .param("size", "2")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray());

    }
```

The test method "shouldReturnAPageWithUserSpecificToDos" throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.domain.Page.getContent()" because "page" is null
```

which occurs when `return ResponseEntity.ok(page.getContent());` is called in the controller method.

However, when I change

```
when(notioRepository.findByOwner("tom", PageRequest.of(0,2)))
                .thenReturn(responsePage);
```

to

```
when(notioRepository.findByOwner(any(String.class), any(Pageable.class)))
                .thenReturn(responsePage);
```

the exception is resolved.

I have not yet figured out what the problem is and could not find any help in the other posts about repositories returning null as they were slightly different problems.

I also like to be specific with this test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock your repository, you pass the PageRequest object with only the page and size parameters, but in your controller you use PageRequest with the sort parameter. Therefore, your mocked repository will return null because it wasn't mocked for that type of PageRequest.
Change the PageRequest object in your test or leave the ArgumentMatcher as is for PageRequest and it should work.